# Edit boolean and operator

Tags: python, boolean, operators

So I've been messing around with the standard operators in classes to try and see what i can make, but i haven't been able to find how to edit the boolean `and` operator.

I can edit the bitwise `&`operator by defining `__and__(self)`, but not the way that `and` behaves. Does anyone know how I can change the behavior of `a and b` where `a` and `b`are instances of the class I'm making?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't, since this does not depend on the type of the operands, but the thruthiness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python 2, `and` and `or` access `__nonzero__`:

```
>>> class Test(object):
...     def __nonzero__(self):
...         print '__nonzero__ called'
...         return True
... 
>>> Test() and 1
__nonzero__ called
1
```

In Python 3, `__nonzero__` has been renamed to `__bool__`.

```
>>> class Test:
...     def __bool__(self):
...         print('__bool__ called')
...         return True
... 
>>> Test() and 1
__bool__ called
1
```

Note that short-circuit evaluation might suppress a call to `__nonzero__` or `__bool__`.

```
>>> 0 and Test()
0
>>> 1 or Test()
1
```

Another speciality to be aware of is that Python is trying to access `__len__` if `__nonzero__` / `__bool__` is not defined and treats the object as truthy if `__len__` returns a value other than `0`. If both methods are defined, `__nonzero__` / `__bool__` wins.

```
>>> class Test:
...     def __len__(self):
...         return 23
... 
>>> Test() and True
True
>>>
>>> class Test:
...     def __len__(self):
...         return 23
...     def __bool__(self):
...         return False
... 
>>> Test() and True
<__main__.Test object at 0x7fc18b5e26d8> # evaluation stops at Test() because the object is falsy
>>> bool(Test())
False
```

> Is there any way i can have this return something other than a bool, like, say, a list of bools?

Unfortunately, no. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) states that the method *should* return `False` or `True` but in fact you get a `TypeError` if you let it return something else.

```
>>> class Test:
...     def __bool__(self):
...         return 1
... 
>>> Test() and 42
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __bool__ should return bool, returned int
>>> 
>>> bool(Test())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __bool__ should return bool, returned int
```

Comment: Is there any way i can have this return something other than a bool, like, say, a list of bools?

Answer (score 5):

The `and` operator converts the first operands to boolean using `__bool__`, and then does a predefined action to the booleans (if `first.__bool__()` is `True`, return second, else return first). There is no way to change this behavior.

Comment: Actually `b.__bool__()` will never be called, I had a slight inaccuracy in my answer.

Comment: @pycoder you actually say *"if `first.__bool__()` is `True`, return second"* but what is returned in this case, is the boolean of the second; not the second iteself.

Comment: @ev `1 and "asdf" == "asdf"`